# What does this equation equivalent to?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have encountered the following *expression and while it looks very familiar, I cannot figure out what it simplifies to or what it represents. My initial guess is that it will be equal to the expected value of something. I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

$$
\binom{n}{l}p^{n-l}(1-p)^{l}
$$

Answer (score 3):

It is just an expression, not an equation: an equation says that two quantities or expressions are equal. It is the general term of the summation that appears in an application of the binomial theorem in probability:

$$1=1^n=\big((1-p)+p\big)^n=\sum_{\ell=0}^n\binom{n}\ell(1-p)^\ell p^{n-\ell}\,.$$

Specifically, if you have a coin that comes up heads with probability $p$, $\binom{n}\ell(1-p)^\ell p^{n-\ell}$ is the probability that you will get $\ell$ tails if you toss the coin $n$ times.